# removing all false elements from a linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a linked list of fish data shown here

```
 //create linked list of fish data called fl
    LinkedList<FishData> fl = new LinkedList<FishData>();
    //Here are a few data items
    fl.add(new FishData("American Eel ", 9, "Summer/Spring ", 25 , false));
    fl.add(new FishData("Hammerhead Shark ", 0, "All Year ", 36, false));
    fl.add(new FishData("Horseshoe Crab ", 7, "All Year except May ", 60, false));
    fl.add(new FishData("Haddock ", 18, "All Year ", 0, true));
    fl.add(new FishData("Tautog ", 16, "late Spring to end of year ", 3, true));
```

I have to use an iterator to remove all of the false elements from this list and print it again.  I think i understand how it works logically, if my data items were only comprised of booleans i think what i did would work, however i dont know how to look at just the boolean field of the element and remove it if its false.  this is what i tried and got a class cast exception, i know what that means i just dont know how to fix it.

```
Iterator itr = fl.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        boolean w = (boolean) itr.next();
        if (w = false)
            itr.remove();
    }
```

UPDATE:

so i edited the code and i now have this

```
 Iterator<FishData> itr = fl.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        FishData b = (FishData) itr.next();
        if (!b.w) {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
    for (FishData element : fl) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

previously i used that for loop to print the whole list but when i use it now, nothing prints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itr.next()` will return the next element in your `LinkedList`, which will be a `FishData` object. You cannot cast this to a boolean variable. Instead you want to access the boolean variable of the `fishData` object. So assuming that your `FishData` class has a `someCondition` boolean variable you can do:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    boolean w = itr.next().someCondition;
    if (w = false)
        itr.remove();
}
```

Or if it is a `private` variable and you have a getter method:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    boolean w = itr.next().isSomeCondition();
    if (w = false)
        itr.remove();
}
```

Also the line `if(w = false)` is incorrect. `=` is the assignment operator. You either need to do `if(w == false)` or `if(!w)`. Or you could simplify this to:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    if (!itr.next().isSomeCondition())
        itr.remove();
}
```

Additionally you need to create a more specific `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<FishData> itr = fl.iterator();
```

Comment: I wondered to myself (and without an IDE in front of me can't confirm) if `itr.next( )` would return an `Object` rather than a `FishData`, since the type isn't specified as `Iterator<FishData>`

Comment: Indeed, OP must also (1) declare his iterator more precisely as `Iterator<FishData>` or (2) cast `itr.next()` into `FishData` type (example: http://tpcg.io/KIq050).

Comment: @Daedalus That is very true. I added that to my answer. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Since return value is a `boolean`, the getter method would likely be called `isSomeCondition()`

Comment: thanks, i modified it but i cant print the new list for some reason, i posted the code i have now as an edit to the original post

Comment: @user9701731 When I run this code it prints out two objects